# Control Add-In for Nav Matrix of textbox(bidimensional) in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, dll, dynamics-nav

I need help creating a CtrlAddIn for Dynamics NAV using C#

I am quite new to matrix and c#, i am using WinForm and VisualStudio to create a DLL.

Here is part of the code:

region Fonctions pilotées depuis Dynamics

```
    // Tout effacer

    [ApplicationVisible]
    public void CleanPanel()
    {
        MainPanel.Controls.Clear(); //Tous les elements seront effacés
    }

    // Gestion des rôles

    [ApplicationVisible]
    public void AjouterRole(string NameL, string idRoleL, int posRoleL)
    {            
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        //Random random = new Random();
        ToolTip TTL = new ToolTip();
        String TooltipL;

        //int randRed = random.Next(1, 255);
        //int randGreen = random.Next(1, 255);
        //int randBlue = random.Next(1, 255);

        //tb.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(randRed, randGreen, randBlue);
        tb.BackColor = Color.Bisque;
        tb.Name = idRoleL;
        //si le texte est plus grand, je mets ...
        tb.Text = NameL;
        if (tb.TextLength > 7)
        {
            string nameO = NameL.Substring(0, 7);
            string points = "...";
            tb.Text = string.Concat(nameO + points);
        }
        else
        {
            tb.Text = NameL;
        }
        tb.AllowDrop = true; //pour le drag and drop                      
        tb.Multiline = true;//pour pouvoir avoir des textboxes de taille differente
        tb.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.None; //pour enlever les scrollbars dans tout les textboxes
        tb.HideSelection = true;//pour ne pas avoir le focus dans le precedent textbox
        tb.Size = new Size(70, 60);
        tb.Left = posRoleL * 70;
        tb.Visible = true;
        tb.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
        //wrap pour que le texte n'aille pas a la ligne et tooltip pour voir le text
        TooltipL = NameL;
        tb.WordWrap = false;
        TTL.SetToolTip(tb, TooltipL);
        //evenement pour le DRAG AND DROP
        //1 Je gere le drag pour pouvoir le bouger
        tb.MouseDown += (senderL, eL) => tb.DoDragDrop(tb.Text, DragDropEffects.Move);
        tb.DragEnter += (senderL, eL) => { eL.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move; };
        //EventControlAddin(3, idRoleL.PadRight(10) + ";" + (string)posRoleL.ToString());
        //2 Je gere le drop pour pouvoir bouger le controle
        tb.DragDrop += (senderL, eL) => { tb.Text = eL.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString(); EventControlAddin(3, idRoleL.PadRight(10) + ";" + (string)posRoleL.ToString()); };
        //evenement pour pouvoir supprimer un role
        tb.MouseEnter += IlumineRole;
        tb.MouseLeave += Eteint;
        //evenement pour modifier le role
        tb.DoubleClick += (senderL, eL) => EventControlAddin(6, tb.Name);

        MainPanel.Controls.Add(tb);

    }

    [ApplicationVisible]
    public void AjouterTotalRole(string NameL, string idRoleL, int posRoleL, string dureeL, string coutL)
    {            
        // Textbox
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.Name = idRoleL;
        tb.Text = NameL;
        int indexMaxRoles = 99;//somme de toutes les lignes + 1 
        // Je dois mettre un tooltip pour comprendre
        ToolTip TTL = new ToolTip();
        String TooltipLCout = "Totaux des rôles en durée et en coût.";
        //Panel contenant les labels
        Panel pn = new Panel();
        pn.Size = new Size(70, 60);
        pn.BackColor = Color.Azure;
        pn.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        pn.Left = posRoleL * 70;
        pn.Top = indexMaxRoles + 1; //Il faut qu'il soit a la casse finale

        Label lb_Duree = new Label();          
        lb_Duree.Text = "Durée:" + dureeL;
        //lb_Duree.Width = 60;
        Label lb_Cout = new Label();
        lb_Cout.Text = "Coût:" + coutL;
        //lb_Cout.Width = 60;
        lb_Cout.Top = 20;

        TTL.SetToolTip(pn, TooltipLCout);
        pn.Controls.Add(lb_Duree);
        pn.Controls.Add(lb_Cout);
        MainPanel.Controls.Add(pn);
    }
```

I need to add the total of the rows and columns as TotalRoles and TotalOperations, and i need to pass to dynamics the lastposition of my textboxes in horizontal and vertical, + 1 for getting the right position. How can i do this? Any help most welcome. Thanks

Comment: Is this for a Silverlight control? We need more details about where exactly the code is going to execute.

Comment: Hi Nicknow, the code is going to execute as a CtrlAddIn for NAV 2013 CRM.

Comment: Okay, so what part of your question is specific to Dynamics CRM? Also, you should add the Dynamics NAV (I'll do an edit for you) to get the right audience.

Comment: C'est quoi ce commentaire en espagnol quand les autres sont en français ? (et au mieux, pour ici, les mettre en anglais).

Comment: traduce : WTF is that spanish comment when all others are in french ? Better to do all in english when posting on Stackoverflow.

Comment: First comment: "changing the properties to do the table as i want"

Comment: Second comment: "I have to delete the space left after dimensioning the cells"...

Answer (score 0):

The control add-in should render the same as a Custom Control in Visual Studio, however there may be some default margins applied. Check that your [margin property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.margin%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is set on your textboxes to explicitly set it to zero.

Also, put your controls inside a better container such as a Panel, TableLayoutPanel or FlowLayoutPanel. These more specialized controls should make it easier to arrange the child elements without having to manually calculate positions, etc.

**Matrix Forms in RTC**

Dynamics NAV already has the ability to display matrix-style forms -- is there a particular use-case where a custom matrix add-in would be more applicable? Distributing a client-side control add-in DLL to all users can be difficult to debug and maintain.

There are [walkthroughs on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee909561.aspx) which explain the process of migrating the classic Matrix forms to the RTC client if that is your underlying objective.

Comment: Developing RoleTailored Client Control Add-ins, this is what i am doing. I explain: I have a main panel, Inside it i want to add some other panels that will contain arrays of textboxes, one of them will be bidimensional and the rest unidimensionals arrays. But my problem is that i can't see the elements Inside the panels. I can see all the panels but no the elements.

Comment: Without any sample code, it's difficult to say. I'd make sure you're adding your panels to the parent control. Try adding something basic like a label to ensure they're displaying at all. More documentation can be found on MSDN -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd983826(v=nav.70).aspx

Comment: i have just refresh my code for you too see, thanks for any help